# Routing problems with Node(Express).js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

I am writing my first program. I am trying to configure routing as follows:

```
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var loginRouter = require('./routes/login');

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/login', loginRouter);
```

**Login.js** file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   res.sendFile('../views/login.html');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Index.js** file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile('../views/index.html');
});

module.exports = router;
```

The index.js file ('127.0.0.1') works, but login.js ('127.0.0.1/login) not. Why?

To be honest, I don't know what to do. The files are almost identical.

Comment: Install loginRouter before indexRouter

Comment: @slebetman Doesn't work. Still error 500

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, can you check if you are getting an error while calling login? your code is working here -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/expressjs-fkrinc?file=index.js,routes%2Flogin.js,routes%2Findex.js

Comment: app.use() is used to put a middleware. So better to nest all the routes in index.js file.

Comment: @lissettdm It works with res.send(), but when I try to send html file then it gives error 500

Comment: @Ani I tried, but the file still doesn't send, just a 500 error

Comment: @Fererra what is the error description? it is also working with `sendFile` -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/expressjs-qd9afm?file=routes%2Findex.js,views%2Findex.html,views%2Flogin.html,routes%2Flogin.js,index.js

Comment: `res.sendFile()` requires an absolute path (no relative paths) unless you explicitly pass the `root` option which determines what the paths are relative to.  From the [doc](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile), ***"Unless the root option is set in the options object, path must be an absolute path to the file."***  I have no idea why you say one works and the other doesn't.  Per the doc, neither should work.  I'd suggest you make these absolute paths or pass the `root` option and see if that fixes it.

Comment: FYI, you can see right in the `res.sendFile()` code [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/2a00da2067b7017f769c9100205a2a5f267a884b/lib/response.js#L440) where it tests to see if there's no `options.root`, then the path must be absolute.

Comment: @lissettdm Thank you very much! I didn't specify root so it didn't work. Now I will know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.sendFile()` requires an absolute path (no relative paths) unless you explicitly pass the root option which determines what the paths are relative to.

From the [doc](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile), ***"Unless the root option is set in the options object, path must be an absolute path to the file."***

I have no idea why you say one works and the other doesn't. Per the doc, neither should work.

I'd suggest you make these absolute paths or pass the root option and that should fix it.

---

You can see right in the `res.sendFile()` code [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/2a00da2067b7017f769c9100205a2a5f267a884b/lib/response.js#L440) where it tests to see if there's no `options.root`, then the path must be absolute.

```
  if (!opts.root && !isAbsolute(path)) {
    throw new TypeError('path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile');
  }
```

---

FYI, further debugging on your part would have probably uncovered this exception `new TypeError('path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile')` which is fairly explanatory about what's going on.  Your `res.sendFile()` is throwing an exception that you aren't catching.  Express ends up catching it for you and probably turns the response into a 500 error.